# Client side validation with CakePHP models

Tags: php, cakephp, jquery-validate

In ASP.NET MVC they use client-side validation via the jQuery validation plugin but instead of setting the rules client-side they use the rules from the model. Does anything exist like this for CakePHP? Where you can have BOTH server-side if no JS and client-side but pulling the rules from the model.

I've taken a look at developing something myself. If you go here: http://www.nerddinner.com/Account/LogOn and try and submit the login form with empty fields, you will see the validation in action for ASP.NET. As you can see they use an unobtrusive plugin to achieve this that uses rules in the form of data attributes.

I'm guessing I could do something to append the Form Helper to add these if validation rules exist... The problem I have is how do I talk to the models? For example say I have a rule that says a field needs to be unique for an email address in the DB how would I achieve this as it needs so form of knowing if it's unique by talking to the server, models and DB.

Any examples would be great or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://github.com/mcurry/js_validate) a plugin for what you need. But it's very old for CakePHP 1.2. So you will have to update it for 2.x or use it as inspiration for your own 2.x compatible plugin.

Comment: Any ideas what needs changing? I've tried to update it to 2.0 conventions but get the error that the Helper class ValidationHelper cannot be found. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.